# Fresh Laravel Installation HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, iis

i have an issue and don't know how to solve it, maybe someone can help me.

I have installed a fresh Laravel APP on my PC with the command laravel new  and pusht it to my Github, after that i changed to my Windows Server and pulled the repo and forwarded my Domain to the public folder. But if i call that domain now i get a HTTP ERROR 500 and i don't know why.

Somehow i also can't call php artisan serve or php artisan key:generate on my Windows Server, there is no output, also it don't create a log file in the storage folder. I'm using PHP 7.4.1 on my IIS Server (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTtxn.png)

This new laravel APP should just a API Backend i have a second one as frontend APP and if i pull these from my repo, i can call that on the Server without any issues also if i call as example php artisan serve there it works only on my fresh installed laravel APP i have this issue.

Someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i'm stupid, my mistake just had to run composer install on my webserver